# SKPaymentTransactionObserver not calling updatedTransactions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have added `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` on `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,
SKPaymentTransactionObserver and conformed to the delegate, I have added in-app purchase capabilities, everything by the book, yet an un-finished transaction doesn't get called upon re starting the app.

I'm really clueless as to why this isn't working.

Note: When I try to buy an in-app I do receive transactions with states such as `.purchasing`, `.purchased` or `.failed` .

Also because of this if I try to buy the same in-app when I restart the app a popup appears saying "This in-app purchase has already been bought" (this transaction should have arrived upon registering the observer).